# Tensorflow Logistic Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, logistic-regression

I am trying to implement: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/wide/index.html
on my dataset.

I am basically trying to do a binary classification (0 or 1) based on some continuous and categorical features.

NaNs were removed, new features created:

```
square_feet = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("square_feet")
guests_included = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("guests_included")
security_deposit = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("security_deposit")
cleaning_fee = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("cleaning_fee")
extra_people = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("extra_people")
```

and

```
neighbourhood_group_cleansed = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_keys(column_name="neighbourhood_group_cleansed", keys=['Bronx', 'Queens', 'Staten Island', 'Brooklyn', 'Manhattan'])

host_response_time = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_keys(column_name="host_response_time", keys=['within an hour', 'within a few hours', 'within a day', 'a few days or more'])
```

-- I got more a lot more features, but I think this conveys the gist.

I copied those functions:

```
def input_fn(df):
    #  Creates a dictionary mapping from each continuous feature column name (k) to
    #  the values of that column stored in a constant Tensor.
    continuous_cols = {k: tf.constant(df[k].values) for k in CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS}
    #  Creates a dictionary mapping from each categorical feature column name (k)
    #  to the values of that column stored in a tf.SparseTensor.
    categorical_cols = {k: tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[i, 0] for i in range(df[k].size)], values=df[k].values, shape=[df[k].size, 1]) for k in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS}
    #  Merges the two dictionaries into one.
    feature_cols = dict(continuous_cols.items() + categorical_cols.items())
    #  Converts the label column into a constant Tensor.
    label = tf.constant(df[LABEL_COLUMN].values)
    #  Returns the feature columns and the label.
    return feature_cols, label


def train_input_fn():
    return input_fn(df_train)


def eval_input_fn():
    return input_fn(df_test)
```

Which will be later used by

```
model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
m = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=FEATURE_COLUMNS, model_dir=model_dir)
m.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=200)
```

If I do a bit of debugging does the function **input_fn()** return a valid **dict** and the **classification**.
However, I get this error:

```
/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column_ops.pyc in check_feature_columns(feature_columns)
    510   seen_keys = set()
    511   for f in feature_columns:
--> 512     key = f.key
    513     if key in seen_keys:
    514       raise ValueError('Duplicate feature column key found for column: {}. '
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Debugging output of **feature_cols** (only an excerpt):

```
'square_feet': <tf.Tensor 'Const_15:0' shape=(10000,) dtype=float64>,
'guests_included': <tf.Tensor 'Const_16:0' shape=(10000,) dtype=float64>,
'security_deposit': <tf.Tensor 'Const_17:0' shape=(10000,) dtype=float64>,
'cleaning_fee': <tf.Tensor 'Const_18:0' shape=(10000,) dtype=float64>,
..
```

and for **label**

```
<tf.Tensor 'Const_27:0' shape=(10000,) dtype=int64>
```

and for **df[LABEL_COLUMN].values**:

```
array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1])
```

Help, hints, tips much appreciated. Those are my first steps with Tensorflow and I don't how to proceed or to further troubleshoot the error.

Thank you!

--- Update ---

I tried to use

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn as learn
```

and now on a DNN classifier, just on the continuous columns

```
classifier = learn.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10], n_classes=2, feature_columns=CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS)

classifier.fit(df_train[CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS], df_train['classification'], steps=200, batch_size=32)
```

and get the same error

```
/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column_ops.pyc in check_feature_columns(feature_columns)
    510   seen_keys = set()
    511   for f in feature_columns:
--> 512     key = f.key
    513     if key in seen_keys:
    514       raise ValueError('Duplicate feature column key found for column: {}. '

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Comment: Can you show the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

When you train the model you are passing it the list `FEATURE_COLUMNS` which I believe you have as a list of strings. When tensor flow loops over this list it is trying to access the key property on a string which fails. you probably want to pass it a list of your tensorflow variables i.e. define a new list `wide_columns`:

```
wide_columns=[square_feet, guests_included,...]
m = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=wide_columns, model_dir=model_dir)
m.fit(...)
```